# Ransomware affected Files can be used.?

Tags: windows, ransomware

My pc was hacked with internal drive and external, i turnoff the computer and disconnected external drives and done clean installation on internal, Does ransomware affected files on external hard drive can be used after scanning by antivirus (quick heal) on another computer

Comment: Ransomeware typically will encrypt every file the user has access to.  If you have already performed a clean install, scanning your external drive is likely pointless, since your external drive never contained the malware.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on which species of ransomware hit you, and whether it encrypted everything it could find or not. I would set up a 'canary' computer and use it to see if the files are in fact readable - not just listable in Explorer; open them up and see if the contents are as you expect. If they are, you're *probably* OK - but if any of the file types allow embedded macros (e.g., any Microsoft Office file), I would assume that they're compromised.